# Swift Label.text = NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I have been trying to set my `usernameLabel.text` to my `loggedIn` name stored in NSUserDefaults.
When debugging I can see that the `NSUser` does have the correct string, here is the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel:: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad(){
  super.viewDidLoad() 
}

override func viewDidApeear(animated: Bool)
{
  let username = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userName")
  if(username != nil) {
    self.usernameLabel.text = username;
  }

}
```

Edit: thats about the code I have in the `ViewController` class. In my `signup` class I store em like this:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userName, forKey: "userName");
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();
```

Comment: How are you storing the username in user defaults?

Comment: am using NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userName, forKey:"userName");

Comment: Your code should work if you stored the right value in your userdefaults. Post some more code of what you're trying to do.

Comment: hmm i couldn't find any .setString.?

i will post some more code for you Ebby.

Comment: Try printing the username before the `if` block and see if the username is holding the value you need to display.

Comment: If i print 
print(username! as String) i get my the correct username out.

Comment: It should be working then. I need to look into your project to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Try this `usernameLabel.text = username as! String`

Comment: i get this error : " Fatal error: unexpectectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" Any idea?

Comment: Make sure your outlet in the code is connected to the label in your viewcontroller on the storyboard.

Comment: Thanks man that worked, idno how but my label wasn't attached in view imust have deleted and remade the label at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. The problem may be occur you not set outlet correctly for UILabel In Storyboard or Xib. Anyway check using `print()` Near your Label. Try this below code.

```
if(username != nil) {
self.usernameLabel.text = "\(username)";
 print("UserName:\(username)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect.
Here you can see it works for me.

[image: Code Image]

Output of your code.
1. InSimulator

[image: output]

2.Using Print

[image: Output1]

Try to clean your project and rerun your app or change the forKey value.

Answer (score -1):

It's easy to solve, you have to force it. Using:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userName")
```

Will give you an optional object. To get the correct string as you want, you should do:

```
let username = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userName") as String!
```

That will give you a String with the contents of what's stored as username on the NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults.